# How do you keep another object's outline visible at all times while working on another object's mesh that is directly above the other objects mesh?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

As the title and pictures explain. How would we do this? :)

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe select the object and in the Properties panel > Object Properties > Viewport Display > enable Wireframe?  Is it what you want?

Comment: I am sorry but that does not solve the issue. I want to be able to see the outline of a mesh under an active mesh that I am actively working on. The outline constantly "disappears" at certain angles even in wire frame mode, thank you though :)

Comment: you can also activate its In Front option in the sale panel

Comment: Thanks for the help, its knowledge to know none the less :)

Answer (score 1):

go in the filter at the top of the window and create a selection restriction and then restrict the object you don't want to select and then you can see the outlines of both the objects but you can select only the objects that have the selection unrestricted |
the filter option -

[image]

Comment: I am sorry but this doesn't work in many situations for my purpose :( Since the object I want outlined is often under the active mesh I need something to show it as it is buried :( I do still  appreciate this as it does help in some situations :)

Comment: then you can go in the object properties of the object underlying and go in view port display and change its display to wire

Comment: That so far appears to solve my issue, of course with a caveat XD I have to set both objects to wire frame mode. If I just set the underlying mesh to wire frame mode the outline of it still... (you won't believe it) disappears at certain angles XD (it appears to improve its visibility at all times though). I am able to differentiate between the wire frames but I would prefer the option to have at least the top (active mesh in this case) not in wire frame mode. Perhaps this might not be possible, either way your help has greatly improved my "work flow" :) Thanks so much :)